# Gradle generates bad eclipse classpath for native dependencies

Tags: eclipse, gradle, sigar

I have a Gradle project that depends on Sigar library, which uses native libraries (as its transitive dependencies). This is a relevant fragment of dependency tree:

```
+--- sigar:sigar:2.0
|    +--- libsigar-amd64-linux:libsigar-amd64-linux:1.0
|    +--- libsigar-ia64-linux:libsigar-ia64-linux:1.0
|    +--- libsigar-x86-linux:libsigar-x86-linux:1.0
|    +--- sigar-amd64-winnt:sigar-amd64-winnt:1.0
|    \--- sigar-x86-winnt:sigar-x86-winnt:1.0
```

Unfortunately, Gradle seems to not recognize that these are native libs and adds them to eclipse classpath just like they were regular `jar`s. This causes errors in Eclipse:

```
Archive for required library: '/home/ghik/.gradle/caches/artifacts-23/filestore/libsigar-x86-linux/libsigar-x86-linux/1.0/so/c9af548445db750ad46e8beb3e77c58ff2315f3f/libsigar-x86-linux-1.0.so' in project 'myproject' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file   
Archive for required library: '/home/ghik/.gradle/caches/artifacts-23/filestore/libsigar-ia64-linux/libsigar-ia64-linux/1.0/so/19d7aa37a3c40b6812a80eca518c6b81fd5c8416/libsigar-ia64-linux-1.0.so' in project 'myproject' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file    
Archive for required library: '/home/ghik/.gradle/caches/artifacts-23/filestore/libsigar-amd64-linux/libsigar-amd64-linux/1.0/so/9481ceafe276c92327f8f3389c5e1c791eac6a81/libsigar-amd64-linux-1.0.so' in project 'myproject' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file 
Archive for required library: '/home/ghik/.gradle/caches/artifacts-23/filestore/sigar-x86-winnt/sigar-x86-winnt/1.0/lib/1a608efcfd2e8358862b7dce02892fa98d63c97b/sigar-x86-winnt-1.0.lib' in project 'myproject' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file  myproject       
Archive for required library: '/home/ghik/.gradle/caches/artifacts-23/filestore/sigar-x86-winnt/sigar-x86-winnt/1.0/dll/14dfa28510c62eee00812e8d231f72ec69ac45b9/sigar-x86-winnt-1.0.dll' in project 'myproject' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file  myproject       
Archive for required library: '/home/ghik/.gradle/caches/artifacts-23/filestore/sigar-amd64-winnt/sigar-amd64-winnt/1.0/dll/b326449439e280c723ac45ada770a8d65a1272cc/sigar-amd64-winnt-1.0.dll' in project 'myproject' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file    myproject       
The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved    myproject
```

How can I fix this?

**EDIT:**

I tried to exclude native dependencies from eclipse classpath like this:

```
configurations {
    natives
    compile.extendsFrom(natives)
}

eclipse {
    classpath {
        minusConfigurations += configurations.natives
        ...
    }
}

dependencies {
    ...

    compile("sigar:sigar:2.0")
    natives("libsigar-amd64-linux:libsigar-amd64-linux:1.0")
    natives("libsigar-ia64-linux:libsigar-ia64-linux:1.0")
    natives("libsigar-x86-linux:libsigar-x86-linux:1.0")
    natives("sigar-amd64-winnt:sigar-amd64-winnt:1.0")
    natives("sigar-x86-winnt:sigar-x86-winnt:1.0")

    ...
}
```

This works only partially. Gradle no longer adds `dll` and `so` files to Eclipse classpath but still adds `lib` files:

```
Archive for required library: '/home/ghik/.gradle/caches/artifacts-23/filestore/sigar-x86-winnt/sigar-x86-winnt/1.0/lib/1a608efcfd2e8358862b7dce02892fa98d63c97b/sigar-x86-winnt-1.0.lib' in project 'myproject' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file
```

Comment: I suppose you don't want the native dependencies on your Gradle class path(s) either (at least not all of them)? How are you currently declaring the `sigar` dependency?

Comment: Sigar dependency is declared as `compile("sigar:sigar:2.0")`. Excluding these dependencies is not bad solution, but not ideal. The problem is only with Eclipse. Gradle itself builds the project without problems.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser I tried to exclude native dependencies from Eclipse classpath (see my edit), but even this doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Can you double-check that your solution only works partially (`gradle clean eclipse` etc.)? I can't think of an explanation why it would remove some files but not others.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the Eclipse buildpath generated by Gradle but I had to adapt the (partly .. `lib` files are not respected?) solution in the following way:

- Newer Groovy versions require an adaption from `minusConfigurations += configurations.natives` to `minusConfigurations += [configurations.natives]`
- I have a **plain directory where the library is installed and not a repository**. It worked for me to use `native files` instead of `natives` (searches only in repositories) inside the `dependencies`section

`build.gradle` excerpt with these two changes:

```
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'java'
```

..

```
configurations{
    natives
    compile.extendsFrom(natives)
  }

sourceSets.main.compileClasspath += [configurations.provided]
eclipse {
    classpath {
      minusConfigurations += [configurations.natives]
    }
  }

dependencies {
    native files('D:/lib/nativeDLL.dll')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with eclipse and gradle 4.3.
I finally found a solution, thought I share it with you all:

```
eclipse {
    classpath {
       file {
            whenMerged { classpath ->
                java.util.List wanted = new java.util.ArrayList()
                def entries = classpath.getEntries()
                entries.each {
                    if (it.path.endsWith('.so')) {
                        println('Removing native library: ' + it.path + ' from eclipse classpath (unreadable to eclipse)')
                    } else {
                        wanted.add(it)
                    }
                }
                classpath.setEntries(wanted)
             }
        }
    }
}
```